# Create a beamer presentation. Where can I get the template?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I want to create a `beamer` presentation with a template like the one used in [this](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/courses/E1Fourier/00700_TransformParseval.pdf) pdf. 
[image]
Can anyone tell, which template this is?

Comment: Did you try asking at the imperial college. I would assume, that it is some custom template. Maybe they send you a template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the document properties it appears to have been made with [`powerdot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) rather than [`beamer`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

[image: Properties for the file linked in the question]

Scanning through the [`powerdot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) manual (Section 7 Available styles) it seems like the `fyma` style (which is bundled with [`powerdot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot)) was used.

[image: Example of fyma style taken from the powerdot documentation]

If you want to exactly replicate the style of the slides you linked to, you may have to contact the original author of the slides for anything they did on top of using the default `fyma` style.